# How to download pdf with pdfkit in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

Good morning, I wanted to be able to open the pdf after generating it.
Or download it.
I tried several ways but I couldn't.
I'll leave a bit of my code below.

I'm using node for backend and react for fontend

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const doc = new PDFDocument;

routes.post('/pdf', (req, res, next) => {
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.pdf')); // write to PDF
  doc.pipe(res);                                       

  doc.fontSize(25)
  .text('text', 100, 100);

  doc.end();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your routes.post, you can return the path of the new pdf file:

```
res.json({path: '/file.pdf'});
```

and then open it in React:

```
window.open(response.data.path, '_blank');
```

Comment: However I found out. But I will cast a vote because it is right.